# Images in jQuery Mobile header not working out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I simply want to mimic the android header using jQuery Mobile. This is what I am getting:

[image]

I simply want the bb where it is, the search, then dollar and then mail icon next to each other. Some how I'm not getting this right. Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" >
            <a href="#" data-role="none" style="border:none;width:20%;">
                <img style="width:20%;" src="css/images/bb.png">
            </a>
            <a href="#" data-role="none" style="border:none;width:20%;">
                <img  style="width:20%;" src="css/images/search.png">
            </a>
            <a href="#" data-role="none" style="border:none;width:20%;">
                <img  style="width:20%;" src="css/images/dollar.png">
            </a>
            <a href="#" data-role="none" style="border:none;width:20%;">
                <img  style="width:20%;" src="css/images/mail.png">
            </a>

        </div>
```

Comment: Pls Add `css` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Grids, http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/grids/

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/qp3bQ/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="header" data-role="header">
        <div id="bb">BB</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">
                    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dot/128/usd_dollar_money_cash.png" width="64" height="64" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519948-008_Mail-128.png" width="64" height="64" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">
                    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-search-128.png" width="64" height="64" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /grid-b -->
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">Content</div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">Footer</div>
</div>
```